# Passing data provider to setUp() in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit

I'm currently trying to pass data from my data provider to the setUp()-method in PHPUnit.

Background: I am using PHPUnit for running frontend-tests in different browsers. The browser should be defined inside the data provider and needs to be known by the setUp()-method.

I understand, that a data provider initially is executed before the setUp()-method (as setUpBeforeClass()) is called. Therefore setUp()-data can not be passed to a data provider. But it should work the other way round, shouldn't it?

Does PHPUnit generate its own temporarily testclasses with data from the data provider "integrated"?

Of course: a workaround could be, to read the XML-file in the setUp()-method again. But that's the last option, I'd consider...

**EDIT:** Provided a small snippet:

part of dataProvider():

```
public function dataProvider()
{
    $this->xmlCnf = $data['config'];
    var_dump($this->xmlCnf); // array with config is exposed
    // [...]
}
```

And the setUp()-method:

```
 protected function setUp()
{
    var_dump($this->xmlCnf); // NULL
    //[...]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In case this is useful to anyone:

The following code should work:

```
public function dataProvider()
{
    return [ [ /* dataset 1 */] , ... ]
}

protected setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $arguments = $this->getProvidedData();
    // $arguments should match the provided arguments for this test case
}

/** 
 * @dataProvider dataProvider
 */
public function testCase(...$arguments) {

}
```

The `getProvidedData` method seems to have been available since PHPUnit 5.6 (which was either shortly before or after this question was originally asked)

Comment: I am trying to make this work but I have 2 data providers for my class. In order to do the same as in your code do I need a specific dataProvider method?

Answer (score 1):

we can make the xmlCnf to static

```
private static $xmlCnf;

public function provider(){
    self::$xmlCnf = 'hello';
    var_dump(self::$xmlCnf); //hello
    return [...];
}

public function setUp() {
    var_dump(self::$xmlCnf); //hello
    parent::setUp();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to access the static variable inside the parent-class, the result still is NULL.
Is there another way, than passing it as an parameter?