# Passing dataProviders data to setup [PHPUnit]

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I am trying for the first time to make PHPUnit work; I want to pass data to the TestCase `setUp()` method such that I can create a new instance for each test. When I write...

```
protected $furniture;

/**
* Instantiate an instance of Furniture for use with all test methods not involved with class constructor objectives
* @dataProvider validConstructorArgumentProvider
*/
protected function setUp($sku, $name, $price, $dimensions) : void
{
    $this->furniture = new Furniture($sku, $name, $price, $dimensions);

}
```

at the beginning of my class, then the test runner errors with:

`ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function WebApp\tests\FurnitureTest::setUp(), 0 passed in /Users/ScottAnderson/Documents/Tech/commissions/shopping_app_test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php on line 1024 and exactly 4 expected`

I have noted [this](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.1/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#data-providers):

> All data providers are executed before both the call to the setUpBeforeClass() static method and the first call to the setUp() method. Because of that you can’t access any variables you create there from within a data provider. This is required in order for PHPUnit to be able to compute the total number of tests.

My specified data provider looks like:

```
private function validConstructorArgumentProvider()
{
    return [
        ["TBL11FN", "Table", 60.0, [120, 50, 70]],
        ["CBN33FN", "Cabinet", 70.0, [60, 120, 210]],
        ["DSK5FN", "Desk", 55.0, [180, 70, 70]],
        ["PCT102FN", "Picture Frame", 13.0, [60, 40, 4]],
        ["LMP40FN", "Lamp Shade", 9.0, [40, 40, 25]]
    ];
}
```

...so maybe it is not possible to feed dataProvider arguments to `setUp()`, but in that case I don't really see what the point of a **per-test-method** setup function is. Is it possible to pass args from a dataProvider to `setUp()?

**N.B**: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397620/passing-data-provider-to-setup-in-phpunit), but I have followed steps for the most favoured answer and I still don't get any luck

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Previously I wrote a completely incorrect answer, however I have now got something which achieves what I want.

It turns out from reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397620/passing-data-provider-to-setup-in-phpunit) more closely that the dataProvider is executed before the setUp function. My amended code looks like:

```
class ThingTest extends TestCase
{

    protected ?Thing $instance;        


    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $args = $this->getProvidedData();

        if (count($args) !== 2)
        {
            $this->furniture = null;
            return;
        }
        $this->furniture = new Furniture(...$args);
    }


    /**
    * @dataProvider instanceProvider
    */
    public function testValidInstanceCanBePrinted()
    {
        //testing code
    }

    /**
    * @dataProvider constructorArgsProvider
    */
    public function testCanBeInstantiatedWithValidArgs()
    {
        //testing code
    }



   public function constructorArgsProvider()
   {
        return [ ["these", "are" ], ["some", "args"], ["as", "example"] ]
}
```

**N.B**: The length test was because I have invalid constructor arguments with an expected exception at the end as an alternate data provider

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to pass data from a data provider to `setUp()`.